# Why do I need '**' when loading json (Python)

Tags: python, argument-unpacking

```
t1 = Tournament("Aeroflot Open", 2010)
json_data = json.dumps(t1.__dict__)
print(json_data)

t = Tournament(**json.loads(json_data)) # <-------------------
print(f"name = {t.name}, year = {t.year}")
```

Could someone explain me why do I need these two asterisks ** when loading the json back. The line is above.

Comment: [Asterisks in Python: what they are and how to use them](https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/) (First hit when I sought for `python documentation asterisk`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, there is unpacking of the iterator using ***** and unpacking of the dictionary using ******.

Let's understand it with examples.

```py
# here is the class
class Tournament:

  def __init__(self, name, age):
     self.name = name
     self.year = year 

# here is init data in your case json.loads will
data = {
  "name": "IPL",
  "year": 13
}
```

python will assign the **key** as a **argument name** and **value** as **argument value** like
**{"name": "IPL", "year": 13}** the **Tournament(name="IPL", year=13)**

```py
tournament = Tournament(**data)
print(f"name = {tournament.name}, year = {tournament.year}")
```

Either you can directly assign the data, like

```py
tournament = Tournament(name="IPL", year=13)
print(f"name = {tournament.name}, year = {tournament.year}")
```

For more understanding, follow this [* and **](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/)